# Bounded continuous functions preserve uniform convergence in probability

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-convergence, probability-limit-theorems

Assume that the sequence of stochastic processes $(X_t^n)_{0 \le t \le T}$ converges to $X_t$ uniformly in probability, i.e.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(\sup_{t \le T} |X_t^n - X_t|>\epsilon)=0 \; \forall \epsilon>0, T>0.$$

How do we show that in this case, for any $f \in C_b^2$, i.e. such that
$$\Vert f \Vert_\infty + \Vert f' \Vert_\infty + \Vert f'' \Vert_\infty \le C<\infty,$$ $f''(X_t^n) \to f''(X)$ uniformly in probability as well?

My attempt:$ \{\sup |f''(X_t^n) -f''(X_t)|>\epsilon\} = \{\sup |f''(X_t^n) - f''(X_t)|>\epsilon, \sup |X_t^n - X_t| < \delta\} \cup  \{\sup |f''(X_t^n) - f''(X_t)|>\epsilon, \sup |X_t^n - X_t| \ge \delta\}.$

The second set is tends to $0$ by assumption that $X_t^n$ converges to $X_t$ uniformly in probability.

But I am having difficulty dealing with the first set. How could we show that this converges to $0$ as well?
I would greatly appreciate some help.

Comment: This seems to be false. The case determinisitic processes indicates that you need $f$ to  be LIpschitz for  the conclusion to hold.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What if we have that $f$ is continuous on compact support, so that $f$ is uniformly continuous. Would it still be false?

Comment: In that case your first set would be empty if $\delta$ is chosen suitably. So  you have no problem with your proof in this case.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Why is the set empty for suitable $\delta$?

Comment: That is  just the definition of uniform continuity.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Actually do we still get the preservation for $f, f', f''$ if $f \in C_b^2$? I.e. $f,f',f''$ are all bounded? This is the exact situation that I see in the textbook that uses this result. I just assumed that the result holds for continuous bounded functions, but I guess we still wouldn't get the result for $f''$?